# Function not evaluating to zero - numerical errors

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, numerical-value

I have a complex but analytical expression that should always evaluate to zero for certain values, but I'm getting strange numerical noise I think I can avoid. The problem seems to occur in a subsection involving logs. Here's the offending section in Mathematica code:

```
  rn = 250*10^-6; e = 0.75;
  f = e*rn;

  test1[r_, t_] := Log[(r^2 - (f^2) (Cos[t]^2) )/(rn^2  - f^2)];
  t1out = Plot[test1[rn*Sqrt[1 - (e*Sin[t])^2], t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Now, I know when $r = r_{n}\sqrt{1 - (e\sin(t))^2}$, then for any value of $t$,

$\frac{r^2 - f^2\cos^2 (t)}{r_{n}^2 - f^2} = \frac{r_{n}^2 - f^2(\sin^2(t) + \cos^2 (t))}{r_{n}^2 - f^2} = 1$

and so the log should always be zero. And for some values of $t$this holds - but for others, I get weird oscillating errors...

[image: errors]

These are very small (order $10^{-16}$) but I think they're avoidable, especially as uncorrected they might mess up some other outputs I need. Is there a way to eradicate this numerical noise, given there's an analytic answer?

Comment: Since you are working with machine numbers, this numerical noise is unavoidable. But you can wrap `test1` in `Chop` for suppressing the noise..

Comment: Though this question is a "simple mistake" as per the close reasons, machine numbers are lately one of my favorite topics. +1

Comment: Thanks, very interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a precision issue.

```
rn = 250*10^-6;
e = 3/4; (* use exact numbers for parameters *)
f = e*rn;

test1[r_, t_] := Log[(r^2 - (f^2) (Cos[t]^2))/(rn^2 - f^2)];
```

Use [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) rather than machine precision.

```
t1out = Plot[test1[rn*Sqrt[1 - (e*Sin[t])^2], t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Alternatively, use `Simplify` and `Evaluate`

```
t1out = Plot[
  test1[rn*Sqrt[1 - (e*Sin[t])^2], t] // Simplify // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Comment: Cheers Bob - makes sense now! I figured it'd evaluate first but doing this forces it to do so!

Comment: @DRG - If you evaluate `Attributes[Plot]` you will see that `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` so evaluation does not occur initially unless forced by use of `Evaluate`.